# Mixed filters, using OR as well as AND, in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In your opinion what would be the best way to do the following?

I want to filter an ElasticSearch query by several ranges that are grouped in an OR filter, and then by one final range that needs to be included as an AND filter. The explanation is a bit crappy but hopefully the pseudo-code below will help...

Basically I tried structuring the following query:

```
{
    "query":{
        "multi_match":{
            "query":"blue",
            "fields":[
                "name"
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort":{
        "_score":{
            "order":"desc",
            "missing":"_last"
        }
    },
    "from":"0",
    "size":"24",
    "facets":{
        "rating":{
            "range":{
                "field":"rating",
                "ranges":[
                    {
                     "from":1
                    },
                    {
                     "from":2
                    },
                    {
                     "from":3
                    },
                    {
                     "from":4
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "price":{
            "range":{
                "field":"price",
                "ranges":[
                    {
                     "to":10
                    },
                    {
                     "from":10,
                     "to":100
                    },
                    {
                     "from":100,
                     "to":1000
                    }
                    {
                     "from":1000
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "filter":{
        "or":[
            {
                "range":{
                    "price":{
                     "from":"10",
                     "to":"100"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "range":{
                    "price":{
                     "from":"100",
                     "to":"1000"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "and":{
            "numeric_range":{
                "rating":{
                    "gte":"4"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This failed with the error that there was "No parser for element [numeric_range]". So I tried replacing:

```
     "and":{
        "numeric_range":{
           "rating":{
              "gte":"4"
           }
        }
     }
```

with:

```
    "numeric_range":{
       "rating":{
          "gte":"4"
       }
    }
```

The query now returns results but it's returning results with prices in the ranges 10-100, 100-1000 and ANY results with a rating greater than 4 (even if their price is outside of the defined range).

Any clues on how I could do this query? Do I need to be using a bool filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah ha, figured it out, with the help of Boaz Leskes over on the ElasticSearch mailing list!

It should be structured like this:

```
filter: {
    bool: {
        must: [
            {
                "numeric_range":{
                    "rating":{
                        "gte":"4"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        should: [
            {
                "range":{
                    "price":{
                        "from":"10",
                        "to":"100"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "range":{
                    "price":{
                        "from":"100",
                        "to":"1000"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```